# How to hide Onsen UI Tabbar whenever keyboard opens?

Tags: cordova, tabbar, onsen-ui

My application contains Tabbar on bottom & I have input fields on that page.But whenever I am trying to enter the input,Keyboard opens & Keyboard is pushing Tabbar up.I only want to push the body part of the page whenever keyboard opens,not Tabbar.So how to do it?Please help.

**My Code** :

```
<ons-tabbar>
  <ons-tab page="SignIn.html"  label="Sign In" icon="fa-sign-in" active="true">
  </ons-tab>
  <ons-tab page="SignUp.html" label="Sign Up" icon="fa-user"  >
  </ons-tab>
</ons-tabbar>
```

Answer (score 2):

The tabbar has an attribute called `hide-tabs`, e.g.

```
<ons-tabbar hide-tabs="true">
  ...
</ons-tabbar>
```

You can use the Ionic keyboard plugin:

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard

Do something like this in a controller where you've injected $rootScope:

```
window.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow', function() {
  $rootScope.hideTabs = true;
});

window.addEventListener('native.keyboardhide', function() {
  $rootScope.hideTabs = false;
});
```

And in your HTML:

```
<ons-tabbar hide-tags="{{ $root.hideTabs }}">
  <ons-tab page="SignIn.html"  label="Sign In" icon="fa-sign-in" active="true">
  </ons-tab>
  <ons-tab page="SignUp.html" label="Sign Up" icon="fa-user"  >
  </ons-tab>
</ons-tabbar>
```

Of course, if you're not using AngularJS you can change the tabbar attribute in the event handlers.